# $x^2 + y^2$ = b has an integral solution.

Tags: number-theory

I would appreciate advice on the following problem (Rosen, chp. 17, #25).

If b is a positive integer, and -1 = $s^2$ mod b for some integer s, then $x^2 + y^2$ = b has an integral solution.

Since -1 = $s^2$ mod b, we know that $s^2$ + 1 = qb for some integer q. However, I cannot think of a way to get rid of the q.

Comment: Please format your question with appropriate markup throughout.

Comment: Reduce to the prime case. It's then a standard result due to Fermat (and there's a large body of similar results), but I don't know what sort of proof you want without further context. Also, you've really done nothing with the problem; put a bit more effort into it.

Comment: ok, thanks. I have been thinking about it, I just haven't made much progress. Do you think you can clarify what you mean by reduce to the prime case, or point me towards similar results by Fermat?

Comment: @anomaly: what an unhelpful and rude comment. So people shouldn't ask questions they don't know how to solve?

Comment: @MartinArgerami: This is a very standard problem and one from a textbook. For problems like that, saying that one has no idea how to start (and just rewriting $s^2\equiv -1\pmod{b}$ is completely trivial) is not reasonable or valid. There's an entire textbook chapter of results to use; it's a homework rather than a research problem, and the material in the chapter can be used to solve it. There's even a section on this particular textbook called "Sums of Two Squares" which is presumably helpful. I don't even know whether to talk about, say, norms in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ because I have no context.